# Perl system call does not work under certain conditions

Tags: perl, system-calls

I have a long perl script (25000 lines) where I need to use a system call once.
If have two datasets, it works great on one, and not at all on the other one.
The only difference that the one that doesn't work is much larger, it takes more memory (half of the available RAM) and takes it more time to run it.
But the code is identical and no system call works when I run the large dataset. I tried 10 different system call all unrelated to the dataset or script, non of them even start when I run the script on the large dataset and all of them work on the small dataset.

I really can not figure this out and I am stuck on it for a while, anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved by someone from Perl Monks: https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116169

On Centos, the hash in memory had to be copied to fork a new process for the system call. The solution is to spin up a worker early and communicate via a channel.

```
use MCE::Child;
use MCE::Channel;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check the return code of the [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0//functions/system.html) call:

```
if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
} 
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it always returns -1

Comment: What's the full error message? A `-1` result should include the ERRNO (`$!`) reason.

Comment: I am running it now with the code you suggested, it takes a while for the results, Thanks!

Comment: I got this output:  "child died with signal 13, without coredump"

Comment: Signal-13 is a SIGPIPE. It would be much more informative here to see the actual code of your `system` call. The manpages for `pipe(7)` note that "If all file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the calling process"

Comment: By the way, originally you said your system call returned -1. Then you said you got a signal-13. Why the difference report?

Comment: I am geneticist so my apologies for my limited knowledge                                            
`my $cmd = sprintf("blastn -query %s -subject %s -out blast_tmp.txt -outfmt 10", $output_file1b, $ref_fileb);
my $output = system($cmd);`
This the current code, but I tried with other more simple commands like `cp` or `mv`, all this system calls work only in one of the two datasets, while the code is exactly the same and `cp` or `mv` system calls were with random files, not related to the dataset

Comment: the $output in the above code gave -1, i added your code below, maybe I didn't do this correct?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with `blastn`. I'm afraid I can't offer much more help. Good luck.

Comment: Ok thanks, but it has nothing to do with bastn, any system call doesn't work. Also same behaviour if I use  qx//

Comment: @Nicolas123 Do these "random files" that don't work have anything different in the filenames from ones that do, like, say, spaces in them?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, no they are the same. I think the problem seems with the difference in virtual memory use of the hash. Any type of system call I tried after the large data files  (245 GB of RAM) are loaded in a hash doesn't work. With smaller data files (10 GB of RAM) all system calls work, but I haven't determined the limit yet. I don't find any info about this problem anywhere.

Comment: The type of system call really doesn't matter, tried 5 different ones, also without input or output files.